# How to filter mailbox enabled users from azure graph /USERS api result

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to get only mailbox enabled users or filter /USERS API result.
There is no direct API I can find to query RecipientTypeDetail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [User -microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) , there is no such query to get users with mailbox enabled i.e. there is  no such property as mailenabled .

If required we may use any programming language to get all users in a for each loop and their mailBoxSettings which contains status.There you can try to filter for only required status of the settings of mail.

You can check this reference to [Find Owners and Members of Mail-Enabled Security Groups using Powershell](https://morgantechspace.com/2019/05/find-owners-and-members-of-mail-enabled-security-groups-powershell.html#:%7E:text=Find%20Members%20of%20mail-enabled%20security%20groups%20We%20can,groups.%201%202%20%24group%20%3D%20Get-AzureADGroup%20-SearchString%20%22TestSecurityGroup%22) if needed.